# Is the method addRound thread safe in the below snippet?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, thread-safety

```
data class Game private constructor(
val id: UUID,
val host: Player,
val rival: Player? = null,
val rounds: List<Round> = emptyList()
    ) {

companion object {
    fun create(host: Player): Game {
        return Game(id = UUID.randomUUID(), host = host)
    }

    fun addRound(game: Game, roundType: RoundType): Game {
        val newRound = RoundFactory.create(roundType = roundType, gameId = game.id)
        return game.copy(rounds = listOf(game.rounds.toList(), newRound) as List<Round>)
    }
}
```

}

Particularly I am interested in the addRound method and if making a new list adding the previous list and a new item is enough.

I have read that in order to make a deep copy you have to explicitly call the .toList() method, is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Not going to "answer" because I don't know Kotlin, but in general, the question is not whether such-and-such _function_ is thread safe. The question is, whether such-and-such _data_ are accessed in a thread-safe way. And, that question can not be answered unless you look at _every_ function that accesses the data. Is there any way that some other function could update the `game` instance while at the same time, your `addRound(game,...)` is copying data out of it? If so, then you might have a problem.

Comment: Well the original idea is to avoid updates altogether and return fresh copy per each method.

Comment: `toList()` creates a shallow copy, not a deep copy. A deep copy would mean each Round instance would also be a new copy. Your current code will crash and is incorrect, though. You're passing a list and an item to `listOf` so you literally have a list of two things, the first of which is a `List<Round>`. It will crash when you try to use it later after casting it to `List<Round>`. You should use `game.copy(rounds = game.rounds + newRound)`.

Comment: OK thanks! And that will be thread safe?

Comment: By using `val` properties exclusively your Game instance is safe from being mutated while it's being copied. But I can't say for sure if your code is thread-safe elsewhere. Two threads might call this function at the same time adding different rounds, and in the code where you call it you could fail to store the new game in a thread-safe manner, so one of the rounds is lost.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I believe a technical term for this is ‘thread-compatible’ — it doesn't guarantee thread-safety on its own, but other code can use it in a thread-safe way if sufficient care is taken.

Comment: Exactly! That is what I was aiming for!